# Strange happenings in my array

Tags: java, arrays

Ok i'm going to show my code and my input and output, Its very strange the value of my array seems to change from one line to the next.

```
import java.io.*;

class chefAndNewRecipe 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/jer/Documents/chef.txt"));
    int testCases = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
    int numGuesses =0 ;

    for (int i=0; i<testCases; i++)
    {
        int ingredients = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());

        String quantity = r.readLine();
        String arr[] = quantity.split(" ");
        int[] numIngredients = new int[arr.length];

        for (int j =0; j< ingredients; j++)
        {
            String temp = arr[i];
            numIngredients[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            System.out.println("This is numIngredients index: " + j + " and value " +numIngredients[i]);//print array location and value
        }
        System.out.println("numIngredients[0]:" + numIngredients[0]); // should be 2 and is
        System.out.println("numIngredients[1]:" + numIngredients[1]); // should be 2 and is 0??
        for (int k = 0; k< numIngredients.length; k++)
        {   
            if (numIngredients[k] <2)
            {   
                System.out.println("Value of numIngredients[k]: " + numIngredients[k]);// print value of numIngredients
                System.out.println("-1");
            }
            else
            {   
                numGuesses += numIngredients[k];
            }

        }   
            System.out.println(numGuesses);
    }
}
}
```

my input is:  
2  
2  
2 2  
1  
6

And my output is:  
This is numIngredients index: 0 and value 2  
This is numIngredients index: 1 and value 2  
numIngredients[0]:2  
numIngredients[1]:0  
Value of numIngredients[k]: 0  
-1  
2  
ingredients: 1  
  
The value of numIngredients[1] changes from 2 to 0 from one line to the next, I can't understand whats going on.

Comment: try using the eclipse debugger and add a breakpoint to that area. it will show you all the variables while its going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using long variable names is useful even for loop variables - you are seem to be using `i` instead of `j`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) // <== possibly arr.length is what you need.
{
    String temp = arr[j]; // <=== was i, same next line
    numIngredients[j] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    System.out.println(
         "This is numIngredients index: " + j + //<== j this line
         " and value " + numIngredients[j]); // <== again, was using [i] 

}
```

Using `currentIngredient` instead of `j` possibly could help with finding an error.

Comment: Thank you ! I was pulling my hair out. Long variable names from now on it is. I will mark as correct answer in few minutes.